# Changing UIElements from outside the view controller

Tags: ios, swift

How would I set a labels text from a file that is not a view controller.
This is what i've tried so far.

```
let viewcontroller = ViewController()
viewcontroller.label1.text = "Hello World"
```

This returns a bad instruction error at runtime

Comment: normally you wouldn't.  You would manage the view from the ViewController.  Pass any data from your model to the ViewController by calling the model from within the ViewController.  Alternatively, if the data is in another ViewController, pass it via segue.

Comment: aha cheers, I realised that I could just do what you said.

Comment: it took me a while to realize that too initially